# Using for loops in row-wise evaluations - R version 4.0.0

Tags: r, for-loop

I have read multiple threads explaining that for loops should be discouraged, if there is a better way I would love to learn. I will say I have tried `summarize()` in conjunction with `group_by()`.

What I am attempting to accomplish, I want to develop a climate database. I have successfully programmed R to download the data directly from the source, and turn a list into data.frame. Now I want to sum and/ or average multiple columns, by month and year. Hence, why I attempted to use `summarize` and `group_by`. My problem is the data comes with codes 'M' or 'T' that I wanted to preserve so I arbitrarily gave them integers of M = 9999 and T = 9998. I figured when it came time to manipulate the code I could use a for loop to evaluate row-wise and turn those 2 placeholders into '0's and return how many 'M's and 'T's where in that subset.

Here is how the data arrives:

```
$data
# A tibble: 935 x 8
   date             datatype station        value fl_m  fl_q  fl_so fl_t 
   <chr>            <chr>    <chr>          <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 2020-01-01T00:0~ PRCP     GHCND:USW0002~    76 ""    ""    W     "240~
 2 2020-01-01T00:0~ SNOW     GHCND:USW0002~     0 "T"   ""    W     ""   
 3 2020-01-01T00:0~ SNWD     GHCND:USW0002~     0 "T"   ""    W     ""   
 4 2020-01-01T00:0~ TMAX     GHCND:USW0002~    39 ""    ""    W     "240~
 5 2020-01-01T00:0~ TMIN     GHCND:USW0002~    -5 ""    ""    W     "240~
 6 2020-01-02T00:0~ PRCP     GHCND:USW0002~     3 ""    ""    W     "240~
 7 2020-01-02T00:0~ SNOW     GHCND:USW0002~     5 ""    ""    W     ""   
 8 2020-01-02T00:0~ SNWD     GHCND:USW0002~     0 ""    ""    W     ""   
 9 2020-01-02T00:0~ TMAX     GHCND:USW0002~    11 ""    ""    W     "240~
10 2020-01-02T00:0~ TMIN     GHCND:USW0002~   -10 ""    ""    W     "240~
# ... with 925 more rows
```

This is the code I use to turn it from lists into a data.frame:

```
## Convert a list from NCDC into a data frame
## mso_data is a placeholder file for the downloaded data from NCDC
## mso_light2 is a placeholder for the destination data frame
## NCDC downloads in a list, the data is stored in the $data portion

library(tidyverse)


## first convert from list to data.frame and remove 'station ID' column
mso_light2 <- mso_data$data[, -3]

## remove time from date group
mso_date <- mso_light2[1]
mso_date <- sub("T.*", "", mso_date$date)
mso_light2$date <- mso_date 

## remove flags for fl_so? and fl_t (time)
mso_light2 <- mso_light2[1:5]

## Change 'T' = 9998 & 'M' = 9999
mso_light2$value[mso_light2$fl_m == "T"] <- 9998
mso_light2$value[mso_light2$fl_q == "M"] <- 9999

## pivot data frame

## eventually use to change column names
## v_names <- c('PRCP', 'SNOW', 'SNWD', 'TMAX', 'TMIN')

mso_light2 <- mso_light2[1:3]

mso_light2 <- pivot_wider(mso_light2,
  names_from = datatype,  
  values_from = value)
```

This is what the data.frame looks like after conversion, I have added columns for month and year and the average daily temperature 'TAVG':

```
# A tibble: 187 x 9
# Rowwise: 
   date        PRCP  SNOW  SNWD  TMAX  TMIN  TAVG month  year
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01    76  9998  9998    39    -5  17       1  2020
 2 2020-01-02     3     5     0    11   -10   0.5     1  2020
 3 2020-01-03     5     8  9998    61   -38  11.5     1  2020
 4 2020-01-04     8  9998     0    33   -66 -16.5     1  2020
 5 2020-01-05     5    10     0    33   -21   6       1  2020
 6 2020-01-06  9998  9998  9998    33   -38  -2.5     1  2020
 7 2020-01-07  9998     0     0    78   -10  34       1  2020
 8 2020-01-08     5  9998  9998    44   -27   8.5     1  2020
 9 2020-01-09  9998  9998     0     0   -55 -27.5     1  2020
10 2020-01-10     8    10     0   -10   -99 -54.5     1  2020
# ... with 177 more rows
```

Now this is was the original code I attempted to use summarize and group_by:

```
## first format mso_light2$date from <chr> to an actual 'date'
install.packages("chron")
install.packages("openair")
install.packages("lubridate")

library("openair")
library("chron")
library('lubridate')

options(stringAsFactors = FALSE)

mso_light2$date <- as.Date(mso_light2$date, "%Y-%m-%d")

## Turning all daily temperatures into an average

mso_light2 <- mso_light2 %>% rowwise() %>% 
              mutate(TAVG = mean(c(TMAX, TMIN), na.rm = T))

## Composing daily data into monthly packages

mso_light2 <- mso_light2 %>%
  mutate(month = month(date)) %>%
  mutate(year = year(date))

##  mso_PRCP <- mso_light2 %>%
##    group_by(month, year) %>%
##    summarise(PRCP = sum(PRCP)) 

##  mso_SNOW <- mso_light2 %>%
##    group_by(month, year) %>%
##    summarise(SNOW = sum(SNOW)) 

##  mso_TAVG <- mso_light2 %>%
##    group_by(month, year) %>%
##    summarise(TAVG = mean(TAVG)) 

##  summarise(SNOW = sum(SNOW)) %>%
##  summarise(TAVG = mean(TAVG))
```

The problem is I do not know of a way to remove my placeholders '9999' & '9998' and make them '0's. So I have been trying to develop a for loop and this is what I have:

```
for(i in 1:length(mso_light2$year[[1]])){
     startDate <- as.character(mso_light2$date[1])

     startDate <- str_split(startDate, "-")
     start_year <- startDate[[1]][1]
     start_month <- startDate[[1]][2]
     start_day <- startDate[[1]][3]
     
     for(j in 1:length(mso_light2$month)){

         mso_monthly <- sapply(mso_light2, 
                               function(x) sum(x[["PRCP"]]), 
                               use.names = 
                                 paste(start_year, '-', 
                                       start_month, sep = ""))
       }
       
     }
```

Please ignore the `sapply()` I have tried every possible function from that family and they all return error messages.

This is the error I keep getting:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (use.names = "2020-01")

`sapply` is just the last function I tried before looking for help, thanks.

Comment: Could you please post a snippet of data as reproducible example. Either use `dput()` or `datapasta` to paste the data (ideally the whole example could be a reprex, but lets start with the data)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are trying to download data from [GHCN](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/) for 2020 for station USW00024153.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dt_path <- "ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/2020.csv.gz"
download.file(dt_path, "2020.csv.gz", mode="wb")

#> ID = 11 character station identification code
#> YEAR/MONTH/DAY = 8 character date in YYYYMMDD format (e.g. 19860529 = May 29, 1986)
#> ELEMENT = 4 character indicator of element type 
#> DATA VALUE = 5 character data value for ELEMENT 
#> M-FLAG = 1 character Measurement Flag 
#> Q-FLAG = 1 character Quality Flag 
#> S-FLAG = 1 character Source Flag 
#> OBS-TIME = 4-character time of observation in hour-minute format (i.e. 0700 =7:00 am)
#>  this list ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/
#>  data dictionary https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/readme.txt
```

The data coming from this FTP server is a little cleaner, at least the dates do not contain the timestamp. I reuse your column names, since data does not have headers. Also note that `readr::read_csv()` (and `data.table::fread()`) handle compressed files just fine, so there's no need to unzip.

```r
dt_colnms <- c("station", "date", "datatype", "value", "fl_m", "fl_q", "fl_so", "fl_t")

dt <- readr::read_csv("2020.csv.gz", col_names = dt_colnms, col_types = 'cccdcccc')
```

The data processing steps include:

1. filtering the station you need and disregarding wind columns which are also present in the dataset.
2. pivot multiple value columns (value and flags you are interested in)
3. averaging the temperature. Since you only have 2 columns I dont see a reason to go `rowwise()`.
4. extracting month and year from character date and converting the date.

```r
dt %>% 
  filter(station=="USW00024153", !str_detect(datatype, "^W")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "date",
              names_from = "datatype",
              values_from = c("fl_m", "fl_q","value")) %>% 
  mutate(value_TAVG=(value_TAVG+value_TAVG)/2,
         month=parse_number(substr(date, 5,6)),
         year=parse_number(substr(date, 1,4)),
         date=as.Date(date, "%Y%m%d"))
```

Now your final step is to check replace values with zero for the rows where fl_m == "T" or where fl_q == "M".

You could have done it before pivoting. Then both pivoting and summarization will become easier:

```r
dt %>% 
  filter(station=="USW00024153", !str_detect(datatype, "^W")) %>% 
  mutate(value=ifelse(fl_m=="T"&!is.na(fl_m), 0, value),
         value=ifelse(fl_q=="M"&!is.na(fl_q), 0, value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "date",
              names_from = "datatype",
              values_from = "value") %>% 
  mutate(TAVG=(TMIN+TMAX)/2,
         month=parse_number(substr(date, 5,6)),
         year=parse_number(substr(date, 1,4)),
         date=as.Date(date, "%Y%m%d")) %>% 
  group_by(month, year) %>% 
  summarize(AVG_TAVG=mean(TAVG, na.rm = TRUE),
            AVG_PRCP=mean(PRCP, na.rm=TRUE),
            AVG_SNOW=mean(SNOW, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   month  year AVG_TAVG AVG_PRCP AVG_SNOW
#>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1  2020    -1.82     6.61   2.58  
#> 2     2  2020    -7.60     9.31  11.3   
#> 3     3  2020    31.6      1.77   0.0968
#> 4     4  2020    69.9     15.1    3.97  
#> 5     5  2020   119.      21.3    0     
#> 6     6  2020   155.      21.5    0     
#> 7     7  2020   191.       2.55   0
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. So everything you guessed was correct except that I wanted the full dataset for each station. For example, 'USW00024153' is valid from January 1, 1948, through the present. I ran into problems using the RNOAA package in that it downloads 1-year maximum at a time. The code I developed to download the entire dataset had some problems that I was going to work on next, hence why only 2020. I will post a new answer to my post showing the problems I have now.

Comment: Well, in that case you can just remove `station=="USW00024153"` from `filter()` and carry on with the whole dataset, although I dont understand how you are going to pivot the data then. You need it by station then?